# DSL connection not working in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, dsl

After freshly installing ubuntu 16.04 my DSL connection was not working. I used pppoeconf and installed `network-manager` `network-manager-gnome` again but it won't work. And also if this file is present `/etc/network/interfaces` network-manager doesn't show the connections I created.

Can anyone help me about how to fix this network manager?

Comment: I have this same problem, it's not working on live image either

Comment: I am fetching same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if ppp is configured in your system:

The `ifconfig` command should have `ppp0` interface. If not, follow the steps below:

1. `sudo pppoeconf`
2. Answer all required questions.
3. Reconnect to DLS or restart or type `sudo pon dsl-provider`.

You should get the connection now. Enjoy!!!

Comment: I tried. But it didn't work for me.